# How can I override or remove a plugin's CSS from my wordpress page?

Tags: css, wordpress

Though I can certainly delete the files or references to them in the plugin code, this is not futureproof when I made plugin updates. They say that if I create a copy of their frontend.css file in my {theme}/{pluginname}/css folder, it will override theirs, but that doesn't work.

So I'm left with a style that takes priority because it matches on one of their containers and overrides my default page links.

For example:

```
.somecontainer a {
    color:red
}
```

I need it gone. Preferably in a way that doesn't use !important or me specifying another instance of the same to override the values because then I have to manage the colors and styles in my original CSS AND in the override.

I already found code to print all enqueued styles and there were none so I can't just unqueue it.

Comment: You can try CSS Unset. The only issue is that its not supported by IE.

Comment: _They say that if I create a copy of their frontend.css file in my {theme}/{pluginname}/css folder, it will override theirs, but that doesn't work._ What exactly doesn't work? Is their stylesheet still being enqueued instead of yours?

Comment: I put an empty file in the folder, but the styles are still being applied instead of disappearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was apparently to DEqueue their styles at the same time I enqueued mine. Not sure why... seems like that would create problems, but this worked:

```
function my_style() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'pmpro_frontend' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'pmpro_print' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_style', 11 );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First you'll need to identify the names/handles that the plugin's stylesheets were originally enqueued under. You can do this
   quickly by running a search on your web server in the plugin's
   directory, e.g. `grep wp_enqueue_style /var/www/mysite/wp-content/plugins/nameofplugin/`
2. Then add a [dequeue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) function to the functions.php file,
   and invoke it on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` with a priority higher than the 
   priority level set on the plugin's original enqueue function.

   ```
   function remove_plugin_styles() {
       wp_dequeue_style( 'name_of_plugin_stylesheet' );
       wp_dequeue_style( 'name_of_plugin_stylesheet_2' );
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_plugin_styles', 99 );
   ```

Comment: by examining $wp_styles, I can see their queued/applied? styles are called pmpro_frontend and pmpro_print. Based on the document inspector, it's the frontend that's the problem, but using your code with those names (either or both) isn't doing it. It's still getting loaded somehow.

Comment: I have a hook on wp_enqueue_script for my own. It seems if I add the dequeue statements there, it works! Thank you!

Comment: Great! Interesting that 'plugins_loaded' hook didn't work. I'll update the answer